# Is there a Mercurial equivalent to gitosis?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I've used ( and still use ) mercurial and git. I have some repos hosted in a server with gitosis which is great and easy to setup. I am looking for a similar tool for hosting mercurial repos.

It must provide minimal acl and ssh access and allow for remote config ( in the style of gitosis's "clone the admin repo and push changes" ).

Extra points for automating hgweb config via said tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [article](http://kurtgrandis.com/blog/2010/03/20/gitosis-for-mercurial/) describes how to set up the gitosis-like [mercurial-server](http://www.lshift.net/mercurial-server.html) for Mercurial.